# How to use parameters in JCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl, rexx

I try to submit job, and all is good, when i hard coding. But I want to use params.

```
//REPORTS   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,**PARM='SDSFINFO FTPSRV01 * hiqual'**
//SYSEXEC   DD DSN=rexx.is.here,DISP=(SHR,PASS)                 
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=A,HOLD=YES                               
//SYSTSIN   DD DUMMY
```

I write my JCL as Procedure. Is it real to describe parameters in the procedure invoice ? Like this:

```
  //stepxx  exec myproc,hiqual=hiqual,owner=*...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two kinds of procedure, cataloged procedure and in-stream procedure.

A cataloged procedure is stored in a library member separate from the execution JCL. This separate library is located by the system searching through a list of such libraries defined to it in `SYS1.PARMLIB`. This list can be overridden with the `JCLLIB` statement in the execution JCL. Your shop likely has a standard location where cataloged procedures are stored.

In-stream procedures are located in the same library member as your execution JCL.  The `PROC` statement must be between your jobcard and the `EXEC` statement that executes the named proc.  The in-stream procedure *must* end with a `PEND` statement.

It is common to use symbolic parameters with procedures, making them more flexible.

You're headed in the right direction...

```
[jobcard is here]
//MYPROC    PROC 
//REPORTS   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='SDSFINFO FTPSRV01 &OWNER &HIQUAL'
//SYSEXEC   DD DSN=[rexx.is.here],DISP=(SHR,PASS)
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=A,HOLD=YES
//SYSTSIN   DD DUMMY
//          PEND
//*
//MYSTEP    EXEC PROC=MYPROC,HIQUAL=ABC,OWNER=XYZ
```

...where the stuff in square brackets must be supplied by you.  This will result in MYPROC being executed as if you had hardcoded...

```
//REPORTS   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='SDSFINFO FTPSRV01 XYZ ABC'
//SYSEXEC   DD DSN=[rexx.is.here],DISP=(SHR,PASS)
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=A,HOLD=YES
//SYSTSIN   DD DUMMY
```

Sometimes procs are coded with default values for symbolic parameters...

```
//MYPROC    PROC ENV='PROD'
//REPORTS   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='SDSFINFO FTPSRV01 &OWNER &HIQUAL'
//SYSEXEC   DD DSN=&ENV..REXX,DISP=(SHR,PASS)
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=A,HOLD=YES
//SYSTSIN   DD DUMMY
```

...and sometimes the default value is documentation...

```
//MYPROC    PROC ENV='SPECIFY_PROD_OR_TEST_OR_QA'
//REPORTS   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='SDSFINFO FTPSRV01 &OWNER &HIQUAL'
//SYSEXEC   DD DSN=&ENV..REXX,DISP=(SHR,PASS)
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=A,HOLD=YES
//SYSTSIN   DD DUMMY
```

...forcing the execution JCL to provide a value or suffer a JCL error at run time.

Note that with the `SET` statement you can use symbolic parameters without needing a procedure, cataloged or in-stream.  This...

```
[jobcard is here]
//  SET HIQUAL=ABC
//  SET OWNER=XYZ
//*
//REPORTS   EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,PARM='SDSFINFO FTPSRV01 &OWNER &HIQUAL'
//SYSEXEC   DD DSN=[rexx.is.here],DISP=(SHR,PASS)
//SYSTSPRT  DD SYSOUT=A,HOLD=YES
//SYSTSIN   DD DUMMY
//*
```

...will give the same results as the first example, without using a proc.

There are usually shop standards to which you will be expected to adhere.  Often mainframe shops have a dedicated group whose function is to run production job streams, scheduling hundreds or thousands of such job streams per day.

Comment: Officially what you have described as _replaceable parameters_ are called **symbolic parameters**. Not to be confused with JCL parameters (positional and Keyword) and also not to be confused with parameters passed to programs written to read the PARM field of a PGM statement.

Comment: @MikeT thanks, I've modified the answer per your comment.